# Mysql joining the same table into multiple columns (denormalizing?)

Tags: mysql

I'm going to simplify my real tables to ask this question
Postulating the following normalized tables

### Soda

```
idSoda
sodaName
```

### Flavor

```
idFlavor
FlavorText
```

### SodaFlavorAsc

```
SodaID
FlavorID
```

Assuming that sodas can have more than one flavor (up to three), how do I create a query that denormalizes the data back into one flat table?

```
idSoda, sodaName, FlavorText(first occurance), FlavorText(second occurance), FlavorText(third occurance)
```

Comment: It would also work for me if it just returned the three flavors in one column, separated by comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For several flavors in the same column use grouping and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT s.idSoda, GROUP_CONCAT(f.FlavorText SEPARATOR ',') as flavors
FROM Soda s
LEFT JOIN SodaFlavorAsc sfa ON sfa.SodaId = s.idSoda
LEFT JOIN Flavor f ON f.idFlavor = sfa.FlavorID
GROUP BY s.idSoda
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew this must be a simple and common thing to do I just wasn't sure how to describe the problem.